# How to use python to get the color sequence of a square?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

[image: Image to be processed]

How to get the color sequence of a square(I have marked it with a yellow box)?
the expected results of this image:
`red,yellow,blue,yellow,yellow`

> - The spacing between the squares may not be fixed
> - only these three colors
> - the squares moves from top to bottom in mid
> - the squares is same size

Comment: What is the expected answer for this image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i had updated this question and description!

Comment: Are the squares always in the same place on the card?

Comment: You shall start with extracting a vertical stripe (single column of RGB pixels). In Python with recent OpenCV any RGB image is a numpy.array, so you can use numpy indexing operator. Then change the colour representation from default (BGR) to HSV (`cv2.cvtColor`) as then the H (hue) layer will give you a clear indication of colour so that classifying/naming it is simple. Then use the constraints (are the tiles same size, is the shift constant?) to split the row of data into sections.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the squares moves from top to bottom in mid